# Pyspark : Adding zeros as prefix in all the values of a column based on a condition

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column A in pyspark dataframe which has values coming like below

```
Column A      Column B
1234           AB
45685          CD
2345           KN
789899         MN
12335577       LN
```

I need to add zeroes in the beginning in column A if the value has less than 8 digit to make the value to 8 digits. So the result should be like below -

```
Column A      Column B
00001234           AB
00045685           CD
00002345           KN
00789899           MN
12335577           LN
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take: First, write a UDF. Second, use the `when` function.

#### UDF

If you are using a UDF you can use regular Python logic to add the expected number of `0`s.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@F.udf(returnType=T.StringType())
def get_string_to_length(text):
    nulls_to_fill = 8 - len(text) 
    return '0' * nulls_to_fill+text    

df = df.withColumn('Column A', get_string_to_length(F.col('Column A')))
```

## When function

Using a when function you can dynamically chain multiple `when` statements behind each other.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

when_function = F.when(
    F.length('Column A') == 8,
    F.col('Column A')
)

for i in range(1, 8):
    when_function = when_function.when(
        F.length('Column A') == F.lit(8 - i),
        F.concat(F.lit('0'*i), F.col('Column A'))
    )

df = df.withColumn('Column A', when_function)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in function [lpad](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?#pyspark.sql.functions.lpad)

```python
df.withColumn("Column A", F.lpad(F.col('Column A'), 8, '0') ).show()
```